# How can I specify the window size/display resolution in Qemu when emulating ARM64?

Tags: qemu

I'm trying to (system) emulate ARM64 using Qemu. My command looks like this:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 \
    -M raspi4b2g \
    -drive file=bin/sd.bin,format=raw,if=sd \
    -kernel bin/kernel8.img
```

I'm using a raspberry pi 4 machine, which is not supported by default Qemu - I'm running a fork that I found. But I don't think that's relevant to my issue. The problem is that the window I get is giant, filling my whole screen. I'd like to tell Qemu to emulate a much smaller screen, 1024x600 (matching my actual hardware). How can I do this?

[This page](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/invocation.html) lists a `-g widthxheight` option, but if I try that I get `Option not supported for this target`, so I guess that's not supported for ARM64.